# How to use Autodock just for (re)scoring

Tags: bioinformatics

I have some protein-ligand complexed that I have been docking with some other software and just want to use Autodock to evaluate those complexes. So, basically I just want to use it as a scoring function to take a look at the energy components - I don't want to re-dock the ligands into the protein binding sites. 
From what I have found on the internet, I came up with this procedure, but I am not sure if this is the right approach, and also I get an error in the last step saying that "atoms are outside the grid".

It would be nice if someone could take a look at it and tell me whether this make sense and if this is the right procedure (and maybe a suggestion for the error source)

**1) Preparing the receptor**

- need to add hydrogens if not present
- adds gasteiger charges to peptide

**input**

- protein.pdb

**output**

- protein.pdbqt

**script:**

- prepare_receptor4.py -r protein.pdb [options]

---

**2) Preparing the ligand**

- add hydrogens if not present

**input:**

- ligand.pdb or ligand.mol2

**output:**

- ligand.pdbqt

**script**

- prepare_ligand4.py -l ligand.mol2 [options]

---

**3) Generate grid parameter file**

**inputs**

- ligand.pdbqt
- protein.pdbqt

**output**

- protein.gpf

**script:**

prepare_gpf4.py -l ligand.pdbqt -r protein.pdbqt [options]

---

**4) AutoGrid: generate maps and grid data file**

**inputs:**

- protein.pdbqt
- protein.gpf

**outputs:**

- protein.glg             Grid Log File
- protein.*.map         affinity maps for different atoms
- protein.maps.fld     Grid data file
- protein.d.map         desolvation map
- protein.e.map         electrostatic map

**command:**

autogrid -p protein gpf

---

**5) Generate docking parameter file**

**inputs**

- ligand.pdbqt
- protein.pdbqt

**output**

- ligand_protein.dpf

**script:**

prepare_dpf4.py -l ligand.pdbqt -r protein.pdbqt [options]

---

**
**

**6) Prepare .dpf file and run autodock for re-scoring**

**
**

Remove seach parameters and append the "epdb" keyword, so that an
examplary .dpf would look like this:

autodock_parameter_version 4.2       # used by autodock to validate
parameter set

outlev 1                             # diagnostic output level

intelec                              # calculate internal
electrostatics

ligand_types C HD N NA OA            # atoms types in ligand

fld rec.maps.fld                 # grid_data_file

map rec.C.map                    # atom-specific affinity map

map rec.HD.map                   # atom-specific affinity map

map rec.N.map                    # atom-specific affinity map

map rec.NA.map                   # atom-specific affinity map

map rec.OA.map                   # atom-specific affinity map

elecmap rec.e.map                # electrostatics map

desolvmap rec.d.map              # desolvation map

move lig.pdbqt                       # small molecule

about 17.6 22.2 32.6         # small molecule center

epdb                                   # small molecule to be
evaluated

**
**

**inputs**

- ligand_receptor.dpf

**command:**

autodock -p ligand_protein.dpf

## Edit

I managed to use AutoDock Vina for re-scoring now, however, the output is not as detailed as the one that would be produced by AutoDock 4.2.

For example, what I get is:

Affinity: -2.06943 (kcal/mol)
Intermolecular contributions to the terms, before weighting:
    gauss 1     : 51.97697
    gauss 2     : 1133.84012
    repulsion   : 7.41516
    hydrophobic : 34.56441
    Hydrogen    : 0.00000

(what is also weird is that the `prepare_ligand4.py` script to generate the .pdbqt file from the mol2 file removed the hydrogens)

In AutoDock4.2, the output would be, for example,

epdb: USER Estimated Free Energy of Binding = -6.54 kcal/mol [=(1)+(2)+(3)-(4)]
epdb: USER Estimated Inhibition Constant, Ki = 15.95 uM (micromolar) [Temperature = 298.15 K]
epdb: USER
epdb: USER (1) Final Intermolecular Energy = -7.14 kcal/mol
epdb: USER vdW + Hbond + desolv Energy = -6.33 kcal/mol
epdb: USER Electrostatic Energy = -0.81 kcal/mol
epdb: USER (2) Final Total Internal Energy = -0.20 kcal/mol
epdb: USER (3) Torsional Free Energy = +0.60 kcal/mol
epdb: USER (4) Unbound System's Energy [=(2)] = -0.20 kcal/mol

Anyone knows if this might be available through VINA somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured it out. Basically there are those following 6 steps:

1. Preparing a protein
2. Preparing a ligand
3. Generating a grid parameter file
4. Generating maps and grid data files
5. Generating a docking parameter file
6. Running AutoDock

Since the details are a little bit too lengthy for this post, I have written it up as a tutorial. A lot of people (like me) seemed to struggle to get it to work, so I thought this write-up could be a useful reference: [AutoDock4.2 re-scoring tutorial](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_autodock_energycomps.html)

Comment: Thanks! Since I didn't find any complete documentation on the internet, I felt like writing it down once and for all: For myself as future reference, and for anyone else who wants to use AutoDock4.2 just for re-scoring

Answer (score 4):

You can use Autodock Vina. It provides an option to calculate local score only.

> displaying the individual contributions to the intermolecular score, before weighting (these are shown with "--score_only")

Autodock is better tool in speed and accuracy than Autodock itself.

For using it, you need :

1) Protein.pdbqt

2) Ligand.pdbqt

3) Config.txt (the confguration file):

> receptor = hsg1/rigid.pdbqt
>
> ligand = ligand.pdbqt
>
> center_x =  2 # Center of Grid points X
>
> center_y =  6 # Center of Grid points Y
>
> center_z = -7 # Center of Grid points Z
>
> size_x = 25 # Number of Grid points in X direction
>
> size_y = 25 # Number of Grid points in Y Direction
>
> size_z = 25 # Number of Grid points in Z Direction

Run your code as :

```
vina --score_only --config config.txt --log your_filename.log
```

for mmore information type:

```
vina --help_advanced
```

source: http://vina.scripps.edu/manual.html#faq

### UPDATE:

Use:

```
prepare_ligand4.py   -A 'hydrogens'
```

for Adding hydrogen

For understanding the scoring of Vina:

[**AutoDock Vina: improving the speed and accuracy of docking with a new scoring function, efficient optimization and multithreading**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3041641)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. However, the output is unfortunately not as detailed as the one that would be generated by AutoDock. I will make an edit to the original question in a few moments - the formatting works better there.